# how to get client IP using socket programming c#

Tags: c#, sockets

Is there anyone who knows how to get client IP address using socket programming while we are requesting the access of file transferring?? I am using C#.

Comment: Are you talking about getting the IP address(s) of the machine you are currently on, or the remote computer that is making a request?

Comment: basically i am developing a application for window mobile and we use xml files to store information in it. so when window mobile application  make a request to save to save files in server than i want that my window application create a folder of that window mobile application and save all file in that folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Socket.LocalEndPoint` or `Socket.RemoteEndPoint` should do the trick, depending on whether you're the client or not.

Answer (score 8):

In order to get the actual IP address:

```
// Using the RemoteEndPoint property.
Console.WriteLine (
"I am connected to " + IPAddress.Parse (((IPEndPoint)s.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString ()) + 
"on port number " + ((IPEndPoint)s.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString ());

// Using the LocalEndPoint property.
Console.WriteLine (
"My local IpAddress is :" + IPAddress.Parse (((IPEndPoint)s.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString ()) +
"I am connected on port number " + ((IPEndPoint)s.LocalEndPoint).Port.ToString ());
```

taken from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx) site:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyxy9k2(v=VS.71).aspx), after the [`AcceptSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket(v=VS.71).aspx) call you are returned a [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=VS.71).aspx).  On this socket you can call [`RemoteEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx)